# Java Script button

Tags: javascript, custom-button

I have a java script button. It alerts the user with some message ‘Invalid operation please contact system admin’.

**New requirement**, I need to display admin name as  link on pop window after the message. When they click the link, it should take them to System Admin chatter page on a new tab.
New message something like this :  ‘Invalid operation, please contact system admin: Razu’

When they click Razu, it must open up a chatter page of razu. System admin name is dynamic value.

I just gave shot with below code.  It is not working. Please help.

var URL = "/" + "{!User.Id}" ;
window.alert(Invalid operation please contact system admin:’ + URL);

Changed the code based on input as below.
It is not going to user page when I click OK on popup window..I tried the window.location.href also.. it is not working..

if (window.confirm('Invalid operation, please contact system admin. \nPress Yes to navigate to Admin Chatter Page.' + "{!$User.Id}"))
{

window.location = '/' + "{!$User.Id}";

}
}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a `confirm` dialog with 'OK/Cancel' buttons instead of URL Link:

```
if (window.confirm('Invalid operation, please contact system admin. \nPress OK to navigate to Admin Chatter Page.'))
{
    //User clicked 'OK'
    window.location = '/' + '{!User.Id}';
}else{
    //User clicked 'Cancel'
}
```

It is not possible to add links inside an `alert` dialog. If you *really* want to place a clickable URL inside a dialog I would suggest to use a more advanced dialog available with jQuery - http://jqueryui.com/dialog/

**EDIT**

If you also do not know how to find your System Administrator user then look at the code below on how to define a `controller` for your VisualForce page that will get you that user:

```
public class AdminController {

    public User AdminUser {get; set;}

    public AdminController()
    {
        List<User> adminUsers = [SELECT Id, FirstName
                     FROM User 
                     WHERE User.Profile.Name = 'System Administrator' AND User.isActive = true];

        if(adminUsers.size()>0)        
            AdminUser = adminUsers[0];
    }

}
```

And then in your VisualForce page you assign that controller either as `<apex:page extensions='AdminController'>` if you already have assigned controller for that page, or if you don't have assigned controller you assign it as `<apex:page controller='AdminController'>` and then your JavaScript code would look like this:

```
if (window.confirm('Invalid operation, please contact system admin {!AdminUser.FirstName}. nPress Yes to navigate to Admin Chatter Page.'))
            {
                //User clicked 'OK'
                window.location = '/' + '{!AdminUser.Id}';
            }else{
                //User clicked 'Cancel'
            }
```

Note that in `adminUsers` query inside `AdminController` you might not want to get the first admin that query returns. You may want to add additional query filter to only return specific admin, etc.

Comment: Thanks. It doesn;t diplay the button 'Yes' or 'No' on Pop up window.

Comment: Yes, my bad, it displays `Ok` and `Cancel` instead. I edited my answer few minutes ago. Does that work for you? Also, see my edit for other ways to add `url` to dialogs.

Comment: Thank you. Please look at my code.. it is not going to my chatter pager at all.. rather it staying at current page..   if (window.confirm('Invalid operation, please contact system admin. \nPress Yes to navigate to Admin Chatter Page.' + "{!$User.Id}"))
{
    
   window.location = '/' + "{!$User.Id}";

}
}

Comment: Does {!$User.Id} returns correct Admin ID value? Try hardcoding this line like: `window.location = '/' + '00524000001at6Y';` (just use some user Id from your org) and see if it will navigate to it when you click `OK` on dialog. Or try with `window.location = 'http://www.google.com';`, and if it navigates to google.com after `OK` is pressed then your `{!User.Id}' is not evaluating correctly.

Comment: Also, add a screenshot of your current popup dialog to your question, that will help with debugging this issue. And finally, `{$User.Id}` will return your ID, not the admin ID. That expression always returns the ID of the currently logged in user that is browsing the page.

Comment: @Razu please check my latest edit. I've added the code for controller part that will query your Salesforce Administrator and assign it to `AdminUser` variable, that you can later use in your VisualForce page. Let me know if this helps?

Comment: it worked for me. My initial question was answered really well. Thanks for the support. I really appreciate your time. i am further working on the script for additional requirements.. Any idea, how to compile the JS script.. currently i get to know the error while running the script.. it doesn't show the error code line.. any tools for that..